# AngularJs hidden NavBar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to hide the navBar when the route is "/"

I succeeded to hide/show the navbar but the problem is that, when the navbar is hidden, the "app-body" div has 50px of padding top (where should be the navbar)

This is my html code

```
<body ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="MainController" ui-prevent-touchmove-defaults>

    <div class="app">
        <!-- Navbars -->
        <div ng-hide="isActive('/')" ng-controller="NavBarController">
        
            <div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-top">
                <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-center" ui-yield-to="title">
                    Mobile Angular UI
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-left">
                    <div ui-toggle="uiSidebarLeft" class="btn sidebar-toggle">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right" ui-yield-to="navbarAction">
                    <div ui-toggle="uiSidebarRight" class="btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Chat
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- App Body -->

        <div class="app-body">
            <ng-view class="app-content"></ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This image shows the layout when the navbar is visible
[image]

This image shows the layout when the navbar is hidden

[image]

As you can see in the second image there is a grey section at the top.
Am I dooing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: post a fiddle so people can see your css too! It might be possible to put a class on the div with ng-controller that gives it a height of 50px instead of body having 50px padding. then wehn that is hidden, so is it's height.

Comment: Try changing the ng-hide to an ng-if. ng-if should remove the element altogether if true.

Comment: You are using ui-router? Just put the navbar inside `ui-view`.

Comment: I posted your "fixed" comment into an answer. You can mark it as accepted to show the problem is solved. Note in [so] changing the title to "solved" is not what we do; instead, we either post an answer of select the one that solved our issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with the following html code

```
    <div class="app">
        <!-- Navbars -->
        <div ng-if="!isActive('/')" ng-include="'navBar.html'" ></div>

        <!-- App Body -->
        <div class="app-body">
            <ng-view class="app-content"></ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to this comment above

Try changing the ng-hide to an ng-if. ng-if should remove the element altogether if true.

Use ngClass to set a conditional class for your layout